# Is it possible to apply conditions to all active record operations on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many active record queries that operate on my Article model. I have just introduced an "active" field in the articles table. Is there any way I could specify that for all my AR queries, I only want to return "active" Articles, and do it without having to change all my existing AR queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20101112113511/http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping